# How to set File Version of DLL from environment variable?

Tags: c#

I have a DLL that needs to be built outside of the normal build environment, but the file version needs to match that of those build inside.  What's the tag required for this?  I've tried `<version>`, `<fileversion>`, and `<productversion>` to no avail.

Comment: It is not specified the project file.  Edit AssemblyInfo.cs instead.

Comment: I need to set the value from a build environment variable; it can't be hardcoded within a .cs file.

Comment: Such is the burden of trying to solve very simple problems with convoluted nonstandard solutions, you can never get any help.  Everybody else uses distributed source control.

Comment: Rely on a build system (such as NAnt) that can take care of this for you. I am not sure if MSBuild would allow such a thing by default

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to do this, but this might be possible if you have the ability to provide some scripting as part of the build (which seems to be the case if you can load the version into an environment variable that is available for the .DLL build, separate from your normal build environment).

Create a saved copy of your AssemblyInfo.cs without the version information in it at all, call it something else like AssemblyInfo.noversion.

Then, before building the DLL but after the environment variable is set, use a command-script or a Powershell script or even a simple C# command-line utility to copy AssemblyInfo.noversion over the existing AssemblyInfo.cs, and then append properly formatted version information tags to it:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("<version-goes-here>")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("<version-goes-here>")]
```

After that is completed, continue with the .DLL build.  This can be done as part of the build itself (e.g. using pre-build events in Visual Studio), or as a manual prerequisite step, depending on how you are building the DLL.

This is certainly a crude way to accomplish what you seem to be asking; however, if you aren't able to use any kind of build management software that could handle versioning for you, this should allow you to do what you requested.